How can a probability density distribution look negatively skewed on a graph but yield a positive skew result in Excel?
I am analyzing data from a young single mothers residential facility and I am seeing probability density plots that look clearly negatively skewed but Excel and calculates the dataset as being very positively skewed (>1). Concerned, I read the discussion below on StackExchange to get a bona fide negative skew case and test it in Excel. I used the example of deaths of Australian men in 2012, which, when plotted certainly looks like a clearly negatively skewed distribution. However when I entered the data into Excel and ran the skew calculation it gave a value >1, indicating significant positive skew. To double check that the results made sense, I also calculated the mean and median for the dataset and sure enough the median was lower than the mean as one would expect for a positively skewed distribution. For those who want to plug and play with the data, here they are...
Upper limit of age group:
1
5
10
15
20
25
30
35
40
45
50
55
60
65
70
75
80
85
90
95
100
Deaths in age group:
565
116
69
78
319
501
633
655
848
1,226
1,633
2,459
3,375
4,669
6,152
7,436
9,526
12,619
12,455
7,113
2,104
My probability density plot agrees with the one posted in the StackExchange discussion I reference below, so I am puzzled at the discrepancy between the appearance of negative skewness, the statement in the earlier StackExchange discussion, and what appears on my Excel sheet.
Any advice on how to reconcile these differences?

(Real life examples of distributions with negative skewness)

Please show us what you did in Excel, because either it is erroneous or (more likely) you did something other than what you claim.

I simply entered the number of deaths in each group as shown in my original post, then used Excel's Skew function.

Good!  That makes the error clear.  Please include that information in your post; people can then vote to re-open it.

More detail: I entered the number of deaths by age group as shown in my original post & below, in cells E3:E24 of the spreadsheet, then used Excel's "Skew" function (syntax below).
565
116
69
78
319
501
633
655
848
1,226
1,633
2,459
3,375
4,669
6,152
7,436
9,526
12,619
12,455
7,113
2,104
241
Formulas:
=SKEW(E3:E24)
=SKEW(E3,E4,E5,E6,E7,E8,E9,E10,E11,E12,E13,E14,E15,E16,E17,E18,E19,E20,E21,E22,E23,E24)
The result was 1.262 each time. Got similar result (1.238) using Prob. Dens. Functions with age differences as bin widths. Please try with these data yourself.

I don't need to--that calculation is the wrong one for the skewness of your data.

@whuber Perhaps it's time for me to come clean on something. I'm not a statistician. I'm a project manager currently supporting a nonprofit for homeless mothers that's redesigning their programs. They have no statisticians so analyzing data to support their decisions fell to me. I've managed to learn the basics, but skew obviously eludes me. Histograms of most of the client data (e.g. age, public support levels, health data) are skewed. A quantitative measure of the relative skew of different need areas would help prioritize their efforts. So, could you please tell me the right calculation?
